# SWIFT 5 - Displaying, mutating and matching with nested Structs

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct, nested

In my app, customers have different accesses to micro services inside the app. A customer has an admin, who can set permission for other users, to control access for his users inside the app.
So I splittet my PermissionData in 2 different sets.

1. Available Services (All services, which my customer can use)
2. Permissions (All permissions, the admin from my customer can set for his users)

My **Customer**-JSON-File looks similar to this:

```
 {
  "AvailableServices": {
    "AssignmentManagement": {
      "AssignmentManager": true
    },
    "UserManagement": {
      "DeviceManager": true,
      "UserManager": true
    }
  },
   more data..
```

Corresponding Struct:

```
// MARK: - AvailableServices
struct AvailableServices: Codable {
    let assignmentManagement: AssignmentManagement
    let userManagement: UserManagement

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assignmentManagement = "AssignmentManagement"
        case userManagement = "UserManagement"
    }
}

// MARK: - AssignmentManagement
struct AssignmentManagement: Codable {
    let assignmentManager: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assignmentManager = "AssignmentManager"
    }
}

// MARK: - UserManagement
struct UserManagement: Codable {
    let deviceManager, userManager: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case deviceManager = "DeviceManager"
        case userManager = "UserManager"
    }
}
```

My **User**-JSON-File looks similar to this:

```
"Permissions": {
    "AssignmentManagement": {
      "ServiceAccess": true
    },
    "UserManagement": {
      "DeviceManager": {
        "ServiceAccess": false
      },
      "UserManager": {
        "CreateUser": true,
        "ListUser": true,
        "ModifyUser": false,
        "ServiceAccess": true
      }
    }
  },
   more data..
```

Corresponding Struct:

```
// MARK: - Permissions
struct Permissions: Codable {
    let assignmentManagement: AssignmentManagement
    let userManagement: UserManagement

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assignmentManagement = "AssignmentManagement"
        case userManagement = "UserManagement"
    }
}

// MARK: - AssignmentManagement
struct AssignmentManagement: Codable {
    let serviceAccess: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case serviceAccess = "ServiceAccess"
    }
}

// MARK: - UserManagement
struct UserManagement: Codable {
    let deviceManager: AssignmentManagement
    let userManager: UserManager

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case deviceManager = "DeviceManager"
        case userManager = "UserManager"
    }
}

// MARK: - UserManager
struct UserManager: Codable {
    let createUser, listUser, modifyUser, serviceAccess: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case createUser = "CreateUser"
        case listUser = "ListUser"
        case modifyUser = "ModifyUser"
        case serviceAccess = "ServiceAccess"
    }
}
```

My current flow:

1. Starting App
2. Load Customer.JSON and decode it
3. User logs in
4. Load User.JSON and decode it
5. Based on User.JSON display all microservices for the specific user

Until here, everything works fine but now an admin logs in and want to create a new user and set his permissions.
I got stuck to display and work with the struct after decoding it from JSON.
I have a tableView, where the admin from my customer can set different permissions for his users.

Flow should be:

1. Admin clicks on "Set Permissions for User XYZ"
2. Based on Customer.JSON display all Microservices and permissions, the customer have access to
3. Create new PermissionObject and set all booleans inside this object, the admin have selected
4. Encode the PermissionObject, create User and store data in Database

Point **2** and **3** is the problem

[image: TableView]

I even don't know what keywords I have to search to solve my problem.
I read about the Mirror-Class to loop through my Structs. Is this a solid suggestion?

Edit: The goal is to display all available services and their possible permissions in my tableview. Inside my tableview the admin can change the value of a single permission (boolean value).
Maybe my data structure is wrong for my use case?!

Comment: Instead of posting your json samples, that looks incorrect btw, why not include the code of structs corresponding to the json in your question and explain what the issue is in achieving what want with this code.

Comment: JSON is right, inside my question its only a snippet.
Updated question with structs and goal

Comment: You know your app the best, but from what I'm reading, I think your data structure is more complicated than it needs to be.  Try simplifying your app based on what you want your app flow to be.  For instance, why do you need Customer.JSON config files?  Could you store that information in CoreData (or another DB)?  Have you considered creating a DB table with all user roles (Admin, normal user) and the permissions based on which role a user has?

Comment: Yes I think also that the structure is too complicated. The Problem about creating a table with Admin, normal user etc. is, that my customer want to create his own groups with different access levels. So every role and their permissions will be variable. Data is stored in DynamoDB. I have to somehow show my admin which Permissions he can set and based on this create a Object with all the selected permissions. The level of variability is the problem, which makes it so complicated